# Java array analog for python list.index()?

Tags: java, python, list

For Python, I can do something like `array.index(element)` to get the `index` for an `element` in `array`. How can I do this in Java using regular arrays, not arrayList? Is there a similar function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Arrays.asList` then use `List.indexOf`.  The other suggestions to use `Arrays.binarySearch` are good but require the array to be sorted.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use [`Arrays.binarySearch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) method (array has to be sorted).

If sorting an array is unacceptable you have only one solution - full scan. Simply loop through the array to find the index of the element. Same can be acheieved by converting array to List using `Arrays.asList` and then using list's `indexOf` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
Arrays.asList(regularArray).indexOf(elementYouWant);
```

or, if the array is sorted, you can use

```
Arrays.binarySearch();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use Java Collections may can use this. You need implements equals method in your class.

```
public int index(Object[] array, Object element) {
    for(int i = 0; i < array.lenght; i++) {
        if (array[i] == element) {
            return i;
        }
        if (array[i].equals(element) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Better be safe w/ `element != null && element.equals(array[i])`. (Both null is covered by the 1st `if`).

Answer (score 1):

The best way is writing your own function. each built-in method has issue like need sorted array for binarySearch or creating a new list object for asList method.

Use a method like this.

```
public int index( int search, int[] arr ){
  for( int i=0; i< arr.length ; i ++ )
    if( arr[ i ] == search)
     return i;
  return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways

1) Arrays.binarySearch

2) or you can loop though and find it.

```
 public int getArrayIndex(int[] myArray, obj myObject)
{
  int length = Array.getLength(myArray);//get the size of the array
  for (int i = 0; i < lenght; ++i)
   {
     if (myArray[i] == myObject)
      {
        return(i);
      }
    }
   return(-1);//didn't find what I was looking for
  }
```